# API request takes very long to load, where is the problem?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, dbal

We have been experiencing issues with a certain database query in Laravel. Does anyone have an idea on how to optimize this code for faster page loading? We have a very sizable database, now it takes about half a minute to load the page.

```
    public function index($year, int $weekStart, int $weekEnd)
{
    $employees = Employee::has('houses')
        ->with(['collections' => function ($collections) use ($year, $weekEnd) {
            $collections->where('year', '=', $year)
                ->where('week', '<=', $weekEnd)
                ->orWhere('year', '<', $year);
        }])
        ->get(['id', 'identifier', 'firstname', 'insertion', 'lastname']);

    foreach ($employees as $employee) {
        $weeks = [];

        for ($week = $weekStart; $week <= $weekEnd; $week++) {
            $weeks[$week] = ['rent' => 0, 'addition' => 0, 'balance' => 0, 'week_balance' => 0];

            $employeeCollectionsInWeek = $employee->collections
                ->where('year', $year)
                ->where('week', $week);

            $employeeRentInWeek = $employeeCollectionsInWeek
                ->where('type', 'rent');

            $employeeAdditionInWeek = $employeeCollectionsInWeek
                ->where('type', 'addition');

            $employeeCollectionsUpToWeek = $employee->collections
                ->filter(function ($collection) use ($year, $week) {
                    return ($collection->year == $year && $collection->week <= $week) || $collection->year < $year;
                });

            if ($employeeRentInWeek->count()) {
                $weeks[$week]['rent'] = round($employeeRentInWeek->sum('amount'), 2);
            }

            if ($employeeAdditionInWeek->count()) {
                $weeks[$week]['addition'] = round($employeeAdditionInWeek->sum('amount'), 2);
            }

            if ($employeeCollectionsUpToWeek->count()) {
                $totalToBePaid = $employeeCollectionsUpToWeek->whereIn('type', ['rent', 'addition'])->sum('amount');
                $totalPaid = $employeeCollectionsUpToWeek->whereIn('type', ['payment_cash', 'payment_card', 'payment_transfer', 'payment_tikkie', 'remission'])->sum('amount');
                $weeks[$week]['balance'] = round($totalPaid - $totalToBePaid, 2);
            }

            if ($employeeCollectionsInWeek->count()) {
                $totalToBePaidInWeek = $employeeCollectionsInWeek->whereIn('type', ['rent', 'addition'])->sum('amount');
                $totalPaidInWeek = $employeeCollectionsInWeek->whereIn('type', ['payment_cash', 'payment_card', 'payment_transfer', 'payment_tikkie', 'remission'])->sum('amount');
                $weeks[$week]['week_balance'] = round($totalPaidInWeek - $totalToBePaidInWeek, 2);
            }
        }

        $employee['weeks'] = $weeks;
    }

    return $employees;
}
```

Kind regards,

Tom van der Hout, Dylan Vollebregt, Dayton de Lange & Daan Jansen

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: We are using MySQL

Comment: Use debugbar. I think your code is running multiple queries on every foreach loop and of a for loop. You may need to refactor

Comment: Can you do that for us? I don't get it. Thank you very much. Laravel is not the easiest out there. Regards, Daan and Dayton 

Comment: do you index your table?

Comment: Hello, we don't know. Previously there was only 1 developer here, he has left and sadly not documented his stuff very well. Regards, Tom